# How do I start to write this XML in Java?

Tags: java, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- Course information -->
<courses>

I don't know how to do this

<course number=" CIS 101">
<title>Personal Computing</ title >
</course>
<course number=" CIS 234">
<title>Introduction to Java Programming</ title >
<prerequisites>
<prerequisite>CIS 101</prerequisite >
<prerequisite>STA 120</prerequisite >
</prerequisites>
</course>
<course number="CIS 304">
<title>Intermediate Java Programming</ title >
<prerequisites>
<prerequisite>CIS 234</prerequisite >
</prerequisites>
</course>
</courses>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the StAX APIs included as part of Java SE 6 and later to create your XML document:

```
XMLOutputFactory xof = XMLOutputFactory.newFactory();
XMLStreamWriter xsr = xof.createXMLStreamWriter(System.out);
xsw.writeStartDocument();
xsw.writeStartElement("courses");
xsw.writeStartElement("course");
xsw.writeAttribute("number", " CIS 101");
xsw.writeStartElement("title");
xsw.writeCharacters("Personal Computing");
xsw.writeEndElement();  // </title>
...
xsw.writeEndElement(); // </course>
xsw.writeEndElement(); // </courses>
xsw.writeEndDocument();
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, i am currently trying out a code i was provided by the professor, and use somewhat of the same code except using filewriter import? as noted i have no idea how it exactly works

Comment: @WalterSolares - Creating an `XMLStreamWriter` on a `FileWriter`?

Comment: so i just finished it, where exactly can i find where the xml file is? there is no errors but when i run it, i cant find where the xml is stored?